# Laravel redirect to blank page after logging in with encrypted user email

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, encryption

I have a client which want to save his data encrypted in the database (email, name etc.). He wants to log in with the email too. I made the functionality to log in with encrypted email but the problem is that after log in I am redirected to a blank page with the url `/login` when I should be redirected to `/business-accounts`. If I delete manually the `/login` from the url I am redirected to the `/business-accounts` which I need to be redirected. Before doing the ecrypted email authentication everything worked fine.

#### AuthenticatedSessionController.php

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    //check user is validated
    User::all()->filter(function ($user) use ($request) {
        if($user->email == $request->email){

            if($user && $user->status==0){
                throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                    'validation' => 'Account not verified.'
                ]);
            }
            //get user email crypted for login
            $request->merge(['email' => User::find($user->id)->get_email_crypted()]);
            
            $request->authenticate();
            
            $request->session()->regenerate();
    
            //set user session
            UserService::set_session($user);

            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

    });
}
```

I printed a dd() before the return and seems like everything is working fine till there.

#### LoginRequest.php

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();
    
    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

#### RouteServiceProvider.php

```
 public const HOME = '/business-accounts';
```

Encryption and decryption is made in the User model with get/setEmailAttribute. In the `authenticate()` method I could see that it is not entering the `if` where `Auth::attempt` is located.
I tried to make it work in `PasswordResetLinkController` too but all I could get is the same blank page with the url `/forgot-password` and no email received in the inbox.
My Laravel version is 8.x.
L.E. I dumped something before the `return redirect()` and I saw that in the browser after the login submit I am redirected back to the `/login` form, so I am thinking that I am getting in a loop or something.

L.E.2.
I somehow resolved this. The thing that I done was changing the crypting method on the email column. I changed the Laravel cripting method with the openssl_crypt function.

#### User Model

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{
    if (!is_null($value)) {
        $this->attributes['email'] = openssl_encrypt($value, "AES-128-ECB", env('EMAIL_ENCRYPT_KEY', false));
    }
}
```

Where the crypting key is located in `.env`.

#### AuthenticatedSessionController.php

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    //check user is validated
    $user = User::where('email', openssl_encrypt($request->email, "AES-128-ECB", env('EMAIL_ENCRYPT_KEY', false)))->first();
    if($user && $user->status==0){
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'validation' => 'Contul nu este verificat'
        ]);
    }

    //set email from request to encrypted email
    $request->merge(['email' => User::find($user->id)->get_email_crypted()]);
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    UserService::set_session($user);

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look in the log file in /storage/logs/laravel.log for the error message

also, you could change the .env file to show_errors = true and it will show the error in the browser

Comment: there is no error in the logs, and I can't find any `show_errors` in the `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

Use `return redirect()->route('your-route-name');` maybe can help you.

Comment: did that, not working as I wish.